# How can I export a template from a DLL?

Tags: c++, templates, dll

Can I export a template from a DLL?

I want to export a function like this from a DLL?

```
template <class T1,class T2)
T1 Create(T2 parameter)
{ 
      T1 retvalue=new T1();
       retvalue.process(parameter);
      // do some other work
      return T1;
 }
```

Can I do this?

If no, Is there any other way to do this? I mean creating an object from the type that defined by user?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot export a template from a DLL. When the template is intantiated, the compiler needs to be able to see all the source code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Supply the source to your template in a header file.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate! I could not understand. When I am creating my DLL, I don't have the source code of T1, but I know that it is derived from a class say MyT1.

Comment: When you're creating the DLL you don't have any reason to instantiate the template at all, so there is nothing in the DLL to export. It is the next user that will do that, and he will need the template declaration to do it.

Comment: You have to understand template instantiation, or specialization. Only when you supply actual specific types, does the compiler need to know what T1 is. And that happens outside the DLL we presume. Put the template in a header file and ship that.